# How to fix images for some products not resizing?

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, magento2.1.6, fotorama-slider

For some reason, the image gallery for certain products isn't resizing its main image, but other products are doing it fine. [Here's an example](https://dutchwaregear.com/11ft-netless.html) of a product that isn't working. [Here's an example](https://dutchwaregear.com/xenon-hex-tarp.html) of one that is. As you can see, the images themselves are the same size, but one is being sized to ~800px, and the other to ~300px. Both have inline styling, but I can't figure out where this styling is coming from.

It's just using the default Fotorama Slider. I've attempted to add various `maxwidth`, `max-width`, `maxheight`, and `max-height` attributes to various places:

- x-magento-init block in `app/design/frontend/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`
- `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`
- `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

No dice - I can get changes to appear on the frontend, but nothing I do fixes the image sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do this comand:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

And i had this error:

> Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): product of memory allocation
>   multiplication would exceed INT_MAX, failing operation gracefully

@MaxL can you help please?

Comment: It seems that you have at least 1 image that is extremely large that is causing the 4GB memory limit to be exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in the CLI from your Magento installation's root folder:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

It might help!

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything. I ran the command then cleared the image cache, and some product images are still too large while others are fine. I did receive quite a few of this error: `libpng warning: Incorrect sBIT chunk length` - could that have preventing some images from resizing?

Comment: You might have some corrupted png files, try re-saving those images in a different format like jpg and re-uploading them?